# How to ssh to another server from GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I need ssh to another server with SSH from Google Cloud Build. I try run this. But it's not working. `echo ${_KEY_STAGING} >> keyStaging && ssh -i keyStaging phihoang@${_SERVER_STAGING} -p 2222`

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? Can you describe more your issue? Error code? Which IP are you using? And can you share your firewall rules?

Comment: Can you share the error message you are seeing?

Comment: @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for '/Users/tudouya/.ssh/vm/vm_id_rsa.pub' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: /Users/tudouya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message that you are receiving:

```
 Permissions 0644 for '/Users/tudouya/.ssh/vm/vm_id_rsa.pub' are too open. It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others
```

It is necessary to run the following command

```
chmod 600 /Users/tudouya/.ssh/vm/vm_id_rsa.pub
```

This command must be executed by the user `tudouya` and will be remove access for other users, fixing your issue.